# Percentage converting function in Panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I saw a function that used to convert the crosstab values into percentage, the code is:

I am really confused what is the meaning of `ser/float(ser[-1])`. What is ser[-1] means, and how this code converts data into percentage.

[image: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/12-pandas-techniques-python-data-manipulation/]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means divide each column by last value of column (value of `All` row), which is converted to `float`.

You can check it by:

```
def percConvert(ser):
    print (ser)
    print (ser[-1])
    return ser / float(ser[-1])
```

But solution can be simplify with parameter `normalize=0` in [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) (column with only ones is removed):

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(data['Credit_History'],data['Loan_Status'], margins=True, normalize=0)
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 100
data = pd.DataFrame({'Loan_Status': np.random.choice(['Y','N'], N),
                   'Credit_History':np.random.choice([0., 1.], N)})
#print (data)

def percConvert(ser):
    return ser / float(ser[-1])

df1 = pd.crosstab(data['Credit_History'],data['Loan_Status'], margins=True, normalize=0)
print (df1)
Loan_Status            N         Y
Credit_History                    
0.0             0.489362  0.510638
1.0             0.415094  0.584906
All             0.450000  0.550000

df1 = pd.crosstab(data['Credit_History'],data['Loan_Status'], margins=True)
        .apply(percConvert, axis=1)
print (df1)
Loan_Status            N         Y  All
Credit_History                         
0.0             0.489362  0.510638  1.0
1.0             0.415094  0.584906  1.0
All             0.450000  0.550000  1.0
```